Handling missing values of a feature in test data that had no missing values in training data
There's a numerical feature named "Fare" in the Titanic - Machine Learning from Disaster Competition dataset on Kaggle. 
The training data has no missing values in "Fare" but the test data has a missing value. I know how to handle missing values in test data for features that had missing values in training data too but this is a first for me, and I can't find an answer on how to go about it.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Imputation should be done after splitting the data so the scenario you are describing is completely normal. The train and test data should be completely separate so there is no cross-talk between the datasets.
As for the imputation itself the best way of doing is to use a model based approach like MICE, calculate the imputation statistic on the training set and then apply it to the test set. So basically in practice train your imputor on the training set and have it predict the missing values on the test set. That way your (pre)modeling is limited to only the training set.
PS: I don't know how large the Titanic dataset is. But if you are training a classifier and the value belongs to a majority class and it is the only missing value, just drop the one missing value. Using imputation on that singular value isn't going to increase the performance of the model.

Thanks, btw the dataset has 891 samples in train and 481 samples in test data.

The Titanic dataset is far too small for a split sample approach to work. Use resampling simultaneously with imputations as done at https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/titanic. Also see Chapter 1 of https://hbiostat.org/rflow

@FrankHarrell the competition already has the data into two sets: train and test, and isn't the whole principle of test data to symbolise unseen data, if I were to use it for handling missing values, it won't make sense. Also , is there any thumb rule on when to use split sample approach

Like earlier competitions on the Titanic the competition has made a major blunder that results in low-precision in both training and testing
